# Prove that an F-homomorphism is an F-automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

This is an exercise from *Field and Galois Theory* written by Patrick Morandi.

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $F$ be a subfield of $K$.
If $\varphi : K \rightarrow K$ is an $F$-homomorphism and $trdeg(K/ F) < \infty$, show
that $\varphi$ is surjective, so that $\varphi$ is an $F$-automorphism of $K$.  And show that it may be false if $trdeg(K/ F) = \infty$.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you can come up with examples for necessity. For sufficiency, I'm not sure what facts you're allowed to use, but one idea is to consider the transcendence degree of $\varphi(K)$ and use additivity.

Comment: Let $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ be a transcendence basis of $K/F$. Let $L=F(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$. Then $K$ is algebraic over both $L$ and $\phi(L)\simeq L$. Any element of $K$ has a minimal polynomial over $\phi(L)$. Port that minimal polynomial to $L$ and use algebraic closure to find the required number of roots. The images of those must be roots of the minimal polynomial you started with etc. Many steps rely on the fact that $\phi$ is injective. Deal with inseparability as needed.